# SVG graphics in Chinese/Japanese don't show up properly in IE8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, unicode, adobe, svg

I was testing an SVG graphic by opening it in IE8 with the Adobe SVG Viewer Plug-in.

The current issue is, all translated SVG graphics with Western Languages(French, Italian, German..) display properly in IE8, only except for the East-Asia Languages(Chinese, Japanese), the characters got shown as boxes.

Since Chrome or Firefox can handle this well, but my client insist on using IE8 to test, could any one suggest a workaround please? Shall I get the client to install a language pack or something to configure the SVG Viewer?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware Adobe's SVG viewer is unsupported? See http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/ for details. No sane IT department would install an unsupported old proprietary program

Comment: @philag I know that. It is because my client INSISTS using IE to view SVG graphics, so I am having a hard time figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first off, are you taking an English SVG and using PHP to substitute in the translations, or are you dealing with a different SVG file for each language with the words already translated? Is the opening XML tag defined as utf8 encoding? And does the final output have to be SVG or could you take an svg and render a png/jpeg?

Our company did some Chinese translations of some pages, and I've found to make sure they displayed properly, I've had to make sure to declare utf8 charset in the page head and write characters as their unicode values (like \u4EA7\u54C1 for the 2 characters that represent "products").

The other suggestion I'd have is to find some Asian Language SVG files on the web that display correct in IE and open them in a text editor to examine how they properly handled the characters. I've used PHP to replace colors on SVG maps but never substituted non-latin characters... please post more info or a follow up if you find the answer elsewhere